# How can I be sure that my assert is actually checking the thing that I want checked?

Tags: alloy

Below is an Alloy model of an email address book. Each name in an address book maps to either a name or an address.

I want each name to eventually map to an address, e.g., Family -> Tom -> Tom_addr. I created a fact to implement this. To check that my fact is correct, I created an assert.

I puzzled for a long time on what to place in the assert. Oddly, the expression that I placed in the "fact" section seems like the right expression to place in assert. But then the assert would be just repeating the fact, which is not helpful. So I created something else to place in assert.

I'm not entirely convinced that what I placed in the "assert" section actually checks that every name eventually maps to an address.

Questions:

In the "fact" section, have I correctly expressed the constraint that each name eventually maps to an address?

In the "assert" section, is there a better way to assert that every name eventually maps to an address?

```
sig Addr {}

sig Name {
    address: some Addr + Name
}

fact {
    // No cycles.
    no n: Name | n in n.^address

    // All names eventually map to an Addr.
    // Here's how I implemented the constraint:
    // There is no name n that is mapped-to (i.e., m -> n), 
    // which does not map-to something (i.e., n -> p).
    no n: Name {
        n in univ.address
        n not in address.univ
    }
}

assert All_names_eventually_map_to_an_Addr {
    all n: Name | some n.^address & Addr
}

check All_names_eventually_map_to_an_Addr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertion that repeats the fact is something that you probably don't want to have as it is indeed useful. (Think of checking/proving a property under an assumption -- an implication of the form *(Q and P) implies P* clearly holds for any *P* and *Q*.)

Having that said, the property:

> every name eventually maps to an address

should be correctly expressed, as given in your code snippet. (The closure can map only to one element of `Address`, since the relation `address` is not defined for instances of `Address`.)